# Sacrificing to regenerate from Supreme Verdict

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have [Varolz, the Scar-Striped](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Varolz%2C%20the%20Scar-Striped) out along with a few minor creatures. My opponent on his turn casts [Supreme Verdict](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Supreme%20Verdict). Before the Verdict resolves can I use Varolz's regenerate ability by sacrificing one of my lesser creatures? Will my Troll survive the Verdict?

Comment: Please accept answers to your questions (by checking the mark next to the answer) to provide closure. Or if no answer is acceptable, please state why.

Answer (score 11):

Sure you can.

With Supreme Verdict on the stack, you respond by activating Varolz's regenerate ability.  This resolves.

Supreme Verdict now resolves, destroying all creatures. Varolz's regeneration shield protects him, and he becomes tapped and survives the Verdict.

Obligatory comp rules citation:

> 614.8. Regeneration is a destruction-replacement effect. The word "instead" doesn't appear on the card but is implicit in the definition
>   of regeneration. "Regenerate [permanent]" means "The next time
>   [permanent] would be destroyed this turn, instead remove all damage
>   marked on it and tap it. If it's an attacking or blocking creature,
>   remove it from combat." Abilities that trigger from damage being dealt
>   still trigger even if the permanent regenerates. See rule 701.12.

This is all pretty basic stuff of course.  Perhaps some confusion arises from the fact that Supreme Verdict "can't be countered".  This just means that it counterspells etc won't work on it, not that there is no possible means of escaping the Verdict's destructive effect.

Comment: Not only can you, but it's to your advantage. If instead of using supreme verdict, they used Righteous Fury, he wouldn't gain the life for your troll, and also wouldn't gain that life for the sucker you sac'd either.

Comment: thank you very much for the answers. While I'v been playing magic for about 3 years my circle of friends and I have never used regeneration abilities till very recently. Good stuff to know.